# How do I find the related euclidian points $(x, y)^T$ to the homogenous form of $(a, b, 2a)^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Given the homogenous representation $(a, b, 2a)^T$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{R} \land a \neq 0$.

How can the related euclidian points $(x, y)^T$ be found?

I would expect the solution to be $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{b}{2a})^T$ which would be a line trough $x = 1/2$.
Is this correct or am I missing some details here? I am rather new to this topic.

Comment: In what sense is $(a,b,2a)^t$ a "representation"? In what way is a point $(x,y)$ "related" to a representation?

Comment: it is a form of homogenous points which represents euclidian points